# Converting any encoding to utf8 in python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm crawling webpages from different websites and they have varied encodings.  A sample of the encodings I get are -

- Big5
- TIS-620
- utf-16le
- shift_JIS
- EUC-JP
- MacCyrillic
- koi8-r

apart from the more common encodings.  I can get the unicode source of the web page by decoding using the above encodings.

My question is this:  I would like to store all the files as utf8.  If I encode the unicode source using utf8, will it work for all webpages?  Does utf8 support all unicode code points?

Comment: The “UTF” part of the name stands for Unicode Transformation Format: any of the “UTF-...” encodings can indeed store all Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and sweet, ........ yes!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, UTF-8 is nothing more than a scheme for storing integers in bytes, in such a way that smaller integers take fewer bytes.  The result is that values less than 128 are stored in one byte so that ASCII is still ASCII.  UTF-8 can represent all Unicode codepoints.